# jQuery "Bad Request 400" in $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, rasa-core

I am using `$.post()` method to request data from localhost. But I am getting `Bad Request 400`.

here is the code:

```
var posting = $.post('http://localhost:5005/conversations/default/parse', {
    query: 'Hi'
});
```

The server I am using is [Rasa-Core HTTP server](https://core.rasa.com/http.html).

Comment: Can you show your route / server-side method? Are you sure it's set to a POST route on the server?

Comment: `400 - bad request` is what the server is responding with - what is the server software you are using? there's nothing inherently with the client code you posted, but `bad request` suggests the server doesn't like your request `The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).`

Comment: is port 5005 used on purpose?

Comment: @JaromandaX I am using Rasa-Core Chatbot Server. Kindly look at the link and tell what I am doing wrong https://core.rasa.com/http.html

Comment: @toffler Yes. it is the server port given.

Comment: I have updated my post. Kindly go through it again.